# jQuery : Error: $("#div.close") is null

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

May be a quick one for you jQuery Experts. I've written my own animate / popout script. But when implementing it into my page, I'm getting an error -

> Error: $("#boxWrapper .close") is null

Any ideas why?

My full code is here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAXPs/)

Cheers

Comment: where u initiate `$(document).ready(function() {// place your code })`?

Comment: y u put `joomla` code into jsfiddle,nobody can test that

Comment: The jsfiddle does not throw this error. You should at least fill the fields correctly. E.g. in the JavaScript field, you should not put `<script>` tags around the code. And `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" />` is not a valid HTML tag. Please create a valid fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You have a script tag in the HTML window, and then the same script in the Javascript window. Remove the script from the HTML, and remove the script tag around the code in the Javascript window.

Comment: @diEcho I've added Joomla code as thats part of the page markup.

Comment: @stu... U just copy the source code of that page, that will come with pure HTML and JS

Comment: @StuBlackett - jsfiddle is not like pastebin - you're supposed to use it to actually make a working example demonstrating a problem or mystery you'd like answered. Just dumping code like that in there is guaranteed not to work, as the jsfiddle back end is not going to evaluate those tags like your own server will.

Comment: I'm not too bothered about that @Pointy. The Joomla stuff is not the issue, as you can see from the jsfiddle example the issue is with the jQuery.

Comment: @StuBlackett I haven't made myself clear.  When you link to a jsfiddle example, people here will expect it to actually demonstrate an issue. If it doesn't work at all, and has all sorts of completely irrelevant problems, it'll waste the time of people trying to help you. If you don't want to get a fiddle working, or can't for some reason, just post your code right here for people to look at.

Comment: Ok gotchya. Although I'm pretty sure the jsfiddle still showed the same error :/ Never mind

Comment: @Pointy & @diEcho The reason the Joomla code was in was that was causing the conflict of libraries. See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right guys. Thanks for the answers, Sorry for the poor use of jFiddle. But I feel that it did need to include the Joomla as that was actually the main issue.

Joomla also use's Mootools JSLibrary,

So I needed to set a noconflict(); for jQuery. and change all references of $ to jQuery.

The actual answer to the code is replace all references of $ with jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#boxwrapper .close').css({"opacity": "0.0"});
    var panel1 =true;
        jQuery('#boxwrapper .button').click(
        function() {

            if (panel1) {
                jQuery('#boxwrapper .open').animate({"opacity": "0.0"}, "slow");
                jQuery('#boxwrapper .close').animate({"opacity": "1.0"}, "slow");
                jQuery('#boxwrapper').animate({"left": "-=200px"}, "slow", function() {panel1 = false;});
            }
            else {
                jQuery('#boxwrapper .open').animate({"opacity": "1.0"}, "slow");
                jQuery('#boxwrapper .close').animate({"opacity": "0.0"}, "slow");
                jQuery('#boxwrapper').animate({"left": "+=200px"}, "slow", function() {panel1 = true;});
     }
   }
 );    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SAXPs/18/) is a working example

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#boxWrapper .close').css({"opacity": "0.0"});
    var panel1 =true;
        $('#boxWrapper .button').click(
        function() {

            if (panel1) {
                $('#boxWrapper .open').animate({"opacity": "0.0"}, "slow");
                $('#boxWrapper .close').animate({"opacity": "1.0"}, "slow");
                $('#boxWrapper').animate({"left": "-=200px"}, "slow", function() {panel1 = false;});
            }
            else {
                $('#boxWrapper .open').animate({"opacity": "1.0"}, "slow");
                $('#boxWrapper .close').animate({"opacity": "0.0"}, "slow");
                $('#boxWrapper').animate({"left": "+=200px"}, "slow", function() {panel1 = true;});
        }
        }
        );    
        });
```

Comment: Cheers Kim, I'm now getting Error: $(document).ready is not a function

Comment: you need to include your jquery before the script

Comment: @Kim I've put that code in the HEAD, Directly after the jQuery. Still gives me that error.

Comment: @Kim - It seems like it was Joomla Conflict error, in that it also loads Mootools. So I've added the noconflict for jQuery to my code. But I'm getting the error from the original code once again.

Comment: I dont know whats worng but it seems to be a Joomla Error and not jquery so i cant help you :/

Comment: Hi Kim, It was a Joomla Error. I've answered the Question myself.. Cheers guys

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `<script>` tags in the JS part. Those are syntax errors. Your JS code will be placed lovingly in an appropriate setting by jsfiddle itself.

Also get rid of the `<script>` block that's copied into the HTML part.

Then, you need to define the "panel1" variable.

Also all those tags (joomla?) aren't going to do anything at all in jsfiddle.

*edit* — given that all these problems stem from what appears to be just lack of familiarity with how jsfiddle works, none of these are likely to be your actual problem. So now you know. Anyway, what's most likely the issue is that you're trying to use jQuery before it's available on the page. Without seeing your *real* code, however, it's hard to say.

Comment: Removed the script from JS Fiddle. I will remove the Joomla Tags.

Comment: his JS code is perfect i checkd on [jslint](jslint.com).but YES js should be not placed in html part in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

There is markup problems, and I think the selector is not the best one to have

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/